# 100 LED floodlight schematic help

Tags: led

I need a floodlight for a large yard.

I want to build one using 100 white LEDs (e.g. 10x10).

The input voltage is not important for me (220v AC , 24v DC ,12v DC all are OK)

How the schematic should be?

Comment: Have you added up the cost of 100 white LEDs?  That's going to be a lot of money.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: 100 5mm LEDs will not be expensive! about 6$ in my country.

Comment: Not at [ebay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/50pcs-8mm-StrawHat-0-5W-High-power-White-LED-Lamp-Light-100MA-/120918830482?pt=US_Car_Lighting&hash=item1c2752ed92) :)

Comment: You might be able to get ordinary low efficiency green or red LEDs for $.06 each, but that's not going to be true for *white* LEDs, especially reasonably efficient ones. Also, where is "my country"? You haven't filled in some stuff in your profile. Remember, that information is a courtesy for us, it's not for you. If you can find reasonable white LEDs for $.06 each, please post a link.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: I bought 50pcs of 5mm white LEDs (http://www.alibaba.com/product-gs/317721444/5mm_round_white_led_diode_Luminous.html) and I paid 6$!

Comment: There are some serious issues with that page.  These are almost certainy of suspect origin and therefore dubious quality.  You say you bought 50, but the minimum order quantity is 1000.  The brightness specs *look* OK, but probably have little to do with actual brightness.  Lifetime is highly suspect. Under "features" they show size a whole bunch of different mutually exclusive packages.  Same for shapes and emitting color.  This looks like someone with low scruples in China trying to make a quick buck off the gullible.  Run away.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: I didn't bought from there I just searched the part number and found that page to show you. I bought those form store and not internet. Yes they're chinese (or japanese! i don't know the difference between these languages) here is something like a datasheet for it: http://www.sparkinter.com/pdf/5AW4UC_8000-10000MCD.pdf nevertheless I bought them and I built the circuit, and it works (except that I need more beam range - these are 40); and I will appreciate if you suggest me a good LED. Thanks anyway;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ledcalc.com/ offer the perfect calculator for your question.

Comment: Is it possible to calculate the luminance?

Comment: That depends on the LEDs. They both have a luminance factor and angle of light, so the distance between each, the wattage and luminance has to be calculated after you choose the LEDs

Comment: My LEDs are these: http://www.sparkinter.com/pdf/5AW4UC_8000-10000MCD.pdf

Comment: The mcd (milli candela, a luminence factor) is explained in japanese or something :P But I think that with a hundred of these you will have good lighting in the dark. I had 40, lit up a room VERY well

Comment: ;-) its mcd is 8000 to 10000 (i say from the file name)

Comment: Oh right, I'll guess you are good to go. Just try with twenty on a breadboard, they will surprise you